# Python equivalent for Ruby combination method

Tags: python, arrays, ruby

Is there ***idiomatic python way*** to list all combinations of specific size from a list?

The following code works in ruby ([here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-combination)), I wonder if there is python equivalent for this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.combination(1).to_a  #=> [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
a.combination(2).to_a  #=> [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
a.combination(3).to_a  #=> [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4]]
```

PS: I am not looking for permutations, but combinations of specific size.

Thanks a lot : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `itertools` module has a `combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) method which does this for you.

```
itertools.combinations(a, len)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.combinations(a, 2)
<itertools.combinations object at 0x109c276d8>
>>> list(itertools.combinations(a, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(a, 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(a, 4))
[(1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Got it. Perfectly as I expected, will accept your answer.